# Rails 5 Active Record Record Invalid Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two Rails model namely **Invoice** and **Invoice_details**.
An **Invoice_details belongs** to **Invoice**, and an **Invoice has many Invoice_details.**
I'm not able to save **Invoice_details** via **Invoice** model using **accepts_nested_attributes_for in Invoice**.

I get the following error :

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)         
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Invoice details invoice must exist):
app/controllers/api/v1/invoices_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Below is the code snippet for `invoice.rb` :

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoice_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_details
end
```

The code snippet for `invoice_details.rb` :

```
class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

The `Controller` code :

```
class Api::V1::InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    comp_id = params[:comp_id]
    if comp_id
      invoices = Invoice.where(:company_id => comp_id)
      render json: invoices, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: "Company ID is NULL" }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def create
    Rails.logger.debug invoice_params.inspect
    invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
    if invoice.save!
      render json: invoice, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: invoice.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:total_amount,:balance_amount, :customer_id, invoice_details_attributes:[:product_id])
  end
end
```

The raw JSON data passed to the controller :

```
{
    "invoice":{
        "total_amount":"100",
        "balance_amount":"0",
        "customer_id":"1",
        "invoice_details_attributes":[{
            "product_id":"4"
        }]
    }
}
```

**invoice_details schema**

```
|id | invoice_id | product_id | created_at | updated_at|
```

**invoice schema**

```
|id| total_amount |balance_amount | generation_date | created_at | updated_at | customers_id|
```

Comment: Try adding `invoice_id` in `invoice_details_attributes` of `invoice_params`

Comment: Can you post your schema for the invoice detail? It seems like something is going wrong with the autosave there.

Comment: @Pavan good catch, I forgot rails 5 now validates the `belongs_to` unless directed otherwise.

Comment: Did that worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know the reason why the above thing was not working however when I explicitly declared a **bi-directional** relation between the two **models** by using `inverse_of`.

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoiceDetails, inverse_of: :invoice
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoiceDetails
end
```

It seemed **Rails** was not setting the **invoice** attribute on the **invoice_details** before attempting to save it, triggering the **validation** errors. This is a bit surprising as other **has_many** relations should have the same save mechanics and were working just fine.

After a bit of googling I found few posts on this behaviour occurring in the older version of Rails, I don't know if that still exists in the new version.
Further can be looked in these links :

1. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-8615049
2. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7661#issuecomment-8614206
3. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-6330795

Answer (score 6):

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Invoice details
>   invoice must exist):

The error is due to you are *not permitting* `invoice_id` while saving `invoice_detail` for `invoice`

In *Rails 5*, the *presence of associated object will be validated by default*. You can bypass this validation by setting `optional :true`

From the [*Guides*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference)

> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the
>   associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set
>   to false.

***Solution:***

Either permit `invoice_id` in `invoice_details_attributes` of `invoice_params`

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:total_amount,:balance_amount, :customer_id, invoice_details_attributes: [:product_id, :invoice_id])
end
```

*OR*

If you wish not to, then set `optional :true`

```
class InvoiceDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, optional :true
end
```

Comment: I did added invoice_id to permit clause but it did not worked, got the same error.
Also I do not want invoice details to be optional as at least one detail should be present for invoice.

Comment: 'def invoice_params
    params.require(:invoice).permit(:total_amount,:balance_amount, :customer_id, invoice_details_attributes:[:invoice_id,:product_id])
  end'